# Kong helm chart certificates

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kong, kong-ingress

im new to kubernetes and helm, and i'm having trouble finding meaningful documentation on the values of this `kong/kong` helm chart.
The values.yaml isn't as descriptive as i would like it to be so here is my question:

There is a certificates setting in the chart that has the following fields:

- issuer
- clusterIssuer
- admin
- portal
- cluster

What are portal and cluster certificates used for? Is it not enough to set a clusterIssuer in the root of the certificates field? Can i have different issuers for these?

I tried looking it up online, all I could find was that if you are using kong hybrid mode then you should set cluster certificates. Is this only needed when I have multiple and or different kong parts communicating with eachother?

Also if anyone has advice on searching for helm documentation i'd appreciate it :)

---

Edit: im only using a kong-ingress in my cluster with the clusters ca.